# Android Access the HTML Tags

Tags: android, tags, html-parsing

I want to access the HTML tags which are present in the web page. I want to change the content of the particular tags. Can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML parser. http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers
You can parse different tags as well as recreate HTML.